# Swift: hiding proprietary implementation code

Tags: swift

In other compiled languages, you have header files and implementation files. For a portable piece of code ("library", "framework", whatever) this means:

- **Header files** are public API information, and are readable and not obfuscated
- **Implementation files** may be public and distributed with the project, or not
- **Object files** are generated from implementation files
- Either the implementation files or the object files must be distributed

In Swift we have:

- **Swift files** contain API and implementation code and are not obfuscated

---

My question regards proprietary code that is currently shipped using the former. They distribute header files, object code and do not distribute implementation files.

If these projects switch to Swift, will they be able to publish modular code without revealing proprietary implementation details? And how?

Comment: Isn't that what they are doing? As you say, it's a library.

Comment: If my answer is so far off maybe you should elaborate a bit on what you do want to know.

Comment: @matt Right, but the library includes header files. The header files are public. In Swift it appears there are no header files. So... does that mean I need to use HTML docs to program against the API and then it magically compiles?

Comment: "In Swift it appears there are no header files" Sure there are.

Comment: @matt Right, this is what I'm stuck on. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html "Everything from your implementation and interface will go directly into this single Swift file."

Comment: Okay, but Swift code is exposed to Objective-C through a header file, and Swift itself has header files. At the top of your Swift file, type `import Swift`. Now command-click on "Swift". Boom, you are in the header file.